# goaccess analystis nginx log - parseing url

Tags: nginx, log-analysis, goaccess

I am using goaccess statistics my ngnix log. But the problem is that the same url have difference parameter.

```
115.*.*.115 - - [01/Nov/2013:06:15:29 +0000] "GET /this/is/example/test.html?ver=53&q=aaaaaa HTTP/1.1" 200 64 "-" "-"
115.*.*.115 - - [01/Nov/2013:06:15:29 +0000] "GET /this/is/example/test.html?ver=53&q=bbbbbb HTTP/1.1" 200 64 "-" "-"
```

I want to ignore the parameter after just statistics url like "/this/is/example/test.html".

How to do that or some other tools can do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -p -e 's/\?.*(\sHTTP)/$1/' log | goaccess
```

should do it.

Comment: Updated answer so it parses only requests.

Comment: GoAccess v0.7 has the ability to remove the query string with `-q`.